# Making a canvas using p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glWON.png)I got an exercise , where i have to create a rectangle-canvas using p5.js , but that canvas will consist small rects ,so i do it , but there is also 1 point in the exrecise . How can i get those small rects in 2 different colors , but 50% of those colores must be green and the other red , using matrix .
Here is the code .

```
        var matrix = [

        ];

        var ab = 36;

        for (var y = 0; y < ab; y++) {
        matrix.push([])
        for (var x = 0; x < 36; x++) {
        matrix[y][x] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
        }
        }
        console.log(matrix)
        var side = 16;
        function setup() {

        createCanvas(matrix[0].length * side, matrix.length * side);
        background('#acacac');
        frameRate()

        }
        function draw() {
        for (var y = 0; y < matrix.length; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < matrix[y].length; x++) {

        if (matrix[y][x] == 0) {
            fill(0, 255, 0)
            rect(y * side, x * side, side, side)
        }
        else if (matrix[y][x] == 1) {
            fill("red")
            rect(y * side, x * side, side, side)
        }



        function Shuffle (arguments) {
for(var k = 0; k < arguments.length; k++){
  var i = arguments[k].length;
  if ( i == 0 ) return false;
  else{
      while ( --i ) {
         var j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
         var tempi = arguments[k][i];
         var tempj = arguments[k][j];
         arguments[k][i] = tempj;
         arguments[k][j] = tempi;
         }
         return arguments;
         }
         }
         }
```

Comment: you are getting some good result.. do you want to replace random function with something exact 50% ?

Comment: Yeaaaahhhh . I exactly need that , I'd just been lookin' for that but i got nothin

Comment: and should they be randomly placed or half can be in a group ?

Comment: Randomly , dude )

Comment: So can u helpme ?plz ?

Comment: you can fill the first half red, second half green then shuffle the array horizontally and vertically

Comment: No dude , I need em to be placed randomly

Comment: shuffling will make their order random

Comment: Well i think that will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so as discussed in comments , the problem reduces to filling **exactly** half the matrix with one color and other half with other.

your matrix is in two dimension i will give a solution in one dimension, which should be quite easy to extend to 2-d

```
var count = 0;
var arr = [];
for( var i = 0 ;i < ab;i++){
  arr[i] = 0;
}
while(true) {
  var i = floor(random(ab));
  if(arr[i] !==1) {
    arr[i] = 1;
    count++;
  }  
  if(count === ab/2) break; // assume ab is even
}
```

there is one more way

fill half the array with 1 and half with 0 and then shuffle the array

you can very easily google algorithms for shuffling,

one pseudocode i could find

```
// after filling half elements with 1 and half with zero
// To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
for i from n - 1 downto 1 do
    j = random integer with 0 <= j <= i
    exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shuffle-a-given-array/

Comment: Look dude , None of algorithms worked normally (
They don't work for multidimensional arrays(

Comment: function Shuffle (arguments) {
 for(var k = 0; k < arguments.length; k++){
   var i = arguments[k].length;
   if ( i == 0 ) return false;
   else{
    while ( --i ) {
    var j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
    var tempi = arguments[k][i];
    var tempj = arguments[k][j];
    arguments[k][i] = tempj;
    arguments[k][j] = tempi;
     }
    return arguments;
    }
 }
}

Comment: Also i added an img , so u can see what happens

Comment: you should return after `for` loop is complete , isnt it ?

Comment: do one thing.. make a one dimensional array of size (ab*ab) and then randomize it as i have told here and from it you can take values

Comment: No , dude , the page doesn't even refresh ((

Comment: share your code if you tried one dimensional array of size (ab*ab) thing.. why dont you make a github gist and share it

Comment: No it's not working ... i tried everything but its not workin

Comment: Well i have no time that's why i didn't install Tower for github well i write the code in answers below *

Answer (score 0):

There it is my problem
                var matrix = [

```
            ];

            var ab = 36;

            for (var y = 0; y < ab; y++) {
                matrix.push([])
                for(var x = 0 ; x<ab;x++){
                    matrix[y][x] = Math.floor(Math.random()*1)
                }
                for(var x = 0 ; x<ab/2;x++){
                    matrix[y][x] = 1
                }
            }




            var count = 0;
            var arr = [];
            for( var i = 0 ;i < ab;i++){
            arr[i] = 0;
            }
            while(true) {
            var i = Math.floor(Random(ab));
            if(arr[i] !==1) {
                arr[i] = 1;
                count++;
            }  
            if(count === ab/2) break; // assume ab is even
            }

            console.log(arr)
            var side = 16;
            function setup() {

                createCanvas(arr[0].length * side, arr.length * side);
                background('#acacac');
                frameRate()

            }
            function draw() {
                for (var y = 0; y < arr.length; y++) {
                    for (var x = 0; x < arr[y].length; x++) {

                        if (matrix[y][x] == 0) {
                            fill(0, 255, 0)
                            rect(y * side, x * side, side, side)
                        }
                        else if (matrix[y][x] == 1) {
                            fill("red")
                            rect(y * side, x * side, side, side)
                        }
                        else if (matrix[y][x] == 2) {
                            fill(255, 255, 0)
                            rect(y * side, x * side, side, side)
                        }
                        else if (matrix[y][x] == 3) {
                            fill(255, 0, 0)
                            rect(y * side, x * side, side, side)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```